# What is the difference between an ADO.NET Source and an OLEDB Source?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm working in SSIS in BIDS 2008 and wondering which I should use as my datasource.  This is a 64 bit box running SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences that are really important depend on the environment in which you use the data soruces.  If your SSIS sources and destinations are all on SQL Server you may observe fewer differences than if you had had other data sources (e.g., Oracle, DB2, etc.).

[Here](http://ssis.wik.is/Understanding_Connectivity_Stacks/ADO.NET_vs_OLEDB) are more details on the differences between the two data sources.

Answer (score 1):

These are the most important diferences:

- Most data flow components work with both data source / data destination types, but there are a few that only work with either OLE DB or ADO.NET (like Lookup)
- In SQL Task, if you use parameters in the query, they are all named `?`, and identified by the order in which they appear. In ADO.NET you can use the `@parameter_name` sintax. So, if you have expressions with many parameters using ADO.NET will avoid mistakes (there are less components with this problem with each new version of SSIS)
- OLE DB is faster in general, most notably if you use the fast load option in a data destination
- if you have the appropriate OLE DB driver you can make both kind of connections (using ADO.NET for OLE DB). The contrary isn't true.

There is a [thorough description of the discuseed difference here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a9e3670-9685-4943-913b-123ecf248a9c/ole-db-vs-adonet).

Answer (score 0):

For my experience the main **practical** difference between them is the ability to use interface to pass parameters to the source query.

[image]